Новые игроки не видят остальных в комнате Photon PUN Unity
Новый игрок заходит в комнату (лобби), остальные в комнате его видят, а он никого. В инспекторе на моменте загрузки сцены появляются все игроки, а потом сразу пропадают. Также появляется ошибка RPC, связанная с синхронизацией ников игроков. Объекты игроков почему-то именно уничтожаются, т.к. на OnDestroy() реакция есть. Поубирал всё, что могло мешать, остался только спавн игроков и старт игры, но все равно такая беда.
Код спавна:
[SerializeField] private GameObject lobbyPlayerPrefab;
[SerializeField] private Transform spawnPos;

private void Awake()
{
    PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;

    Vector3 offset = new(Random.Range(-3, 4), 0, Random.Range(-1, 2));
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(lobbyPlayerPrefab.name, spawnPos.position + offset, Quaternion.identity, 0);
}

Переход в лобби делал через SceneManager.LoadScene("Lobby"); и PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Lobby");. Всё одинаково.
Также эксперементировал с PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene, но ничего не меняется.
Иногда бывает, когда заходит второй игрок, то он видит хоста и все нормально. Но когда заходит третий игрок, он уже никого не видит, а первые два видят всех. Но как правило, первый игрок (хост) видит всех, второй игроков видит только третьего, а трейтий не видит никого.
В чём может быть проблема?
